# add data to gridView on form from another class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can i append data to my dataGridView on form, from another class?

here is class:

```
class TermSh
    {

        public HttpWebRequest request_get_page_with_captcha;
        public HttpWebResponse response_get_page_with_captcha;
        public string url;
        public Form1 form1;
        public BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        public int id = 0;



        public TermSh(Form1 form1)
        {
            this.form1 = form1;
            form1.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }

        public void somemethod()
        {
            try
            {                

                cookies += response_get_page_with_captcha.Headers["Set-Cookie"];


                bindingSource1.Add(new Log(id++, DateTime.Now, cookies));
                form1.dataGridView1.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

and form class:

```
TermSh term_sh = new TermSh(this);
term_sh.somemethod();
```

what i do wrong? why my datagridview is empty after code executing, but with debug i see, that bindingSource1 is not empty.
how to add data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , the way you are going to achieve your goal is incorrect.
first of all, I think passing Form class to a class is very very bad. and then you can simply manipulate a list and return the value and using this value (list) in your Form.

I think it's better to do like this:
[EDIT 1] this following class, is your ptimary class that has a method and this method return a new Log, and you can add this return value to the datagridview in the Form1.

```
class TermSh
{

    public HttpWebRequest request_get_page_with_captcha;
    public HttpWebResponse response_get_page_with_captcha;
    public string url;
    public int id = 0;

    public List<Log> somemethod()
    {
        try
        {                

            cookies += response_get_page_with_captcha.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

            return new Log(id++, DateTime.Now, cookies); //use this return value in your Form and update datagridview 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT 2] after that: you must prepare Log Class to be used as a collection in bindingSource (Form1.bindingSource) and update gridView. and the Following code show the Log class:

```
class Log
{
    private int id;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private string log_text;

    public Log(int id, DateTime datetime, string log_text)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.datetime = datetime;
        this.log_text = log_text;
    }

    #region properties
    public int ID { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
    public DateTime DATE_TIME { get { return datetime; } set { datetime = value; } }
    public string LOG_TEXT { get { return log_text; } set { log_text = value; } }
    #endregion
}
```

[Edit 3] and this code in the Form1, use the return value of class TermSh, and populate the dataGridView:

```
TermSh term_sh = new TermSh(city, type, null, null);
logList.Add(term_sh.getPageWithCaptchaConnection());

logBindingSource.DataSource = logList;
logBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

[EDIT 4] so if you have a question that : "how use this class as a collection in bindingSource??". It's simple, you can populate a dataGridView with objects: [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) is helpful.

Comment: and how to do without passing form class to another class?

Comment: also: then you can simply manipulate a list and return the value and using this value ...   HOW?

Comment: you can use this class in your Form? for example in the form:
     TermSh tsh = new TermSh();
     List<Log> ls = tsh.somemethode();
     bindingsource.DataSource = ls;

Comment: codeis now clear, but datagridview is still empty... will take a look tomorow. now i set you +1

Comment: i will accept, but: maybe i could give you this project, and you take i little look? where i can send it?

Comment: it is [my homepage](http://mostafa.heidary.student.um.ac.ir). u can find my email.

Comment: hm,  mostafa8026@gmail.com was not delivered, here is link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/konslat.zip you must select "Гродно, Шенген, Покупки" and click button Добавить поток, and you will go to method.
 
i try as you say, but nothing happend)

Comment: oh, there is a lot of problem, ASAP I give u a solution. with a glance, u must consider this hints: 1- your dataGridView doesn't have any bindings. 2- maybe your Log class with properties is a good dataSource for the gridView. and 3- things that I write in this post.

Comment: maybe, everybody make mistakes, it's good that somebody help's you with understanding on first steps)

Comment: do you have some progress?

Comment: hey @ValdisAzamaris, you can see my edited answer, and [**from this link**](https://www.mediafire.com/?ldipvgacuucmcsh) you can download my revised version.

Comment: you're welcome, I've removed the link from mediafire.

Comment: hm, maybe it is stupid question, but: you can see that your return new Log(id++, DateTime.Now, cookies);  but! how can i do, when in one construction i have many log events, and i must return all them?

Comment: add them to a list `List<Log> logList = new List<Log>; logList.add(...)` and then return the value.

Comment: yes i done this before, but on form i see last instance, also my method is Log - type, not list...

Comment: you return a List<Log>, ok, and then in the Form1 write this code: `bindingSource.DataSource = (return list value); bindingSource.resetBindings(False);`

Comment: also i try to add method in Log class: public List<Log> add_collection(Log log)
        {
            List<Log> retList = new List<Log>();
            retList.Add(log);
            return retList;
        }

Comment: and then in TermSh push all to list via this method, and then return Log method-variable

Comment: I think creating a new question is better (create a new question and link that here)... I'll fix it there.